# How to swich off the log4j debug information of iBatis and Struts2 in my project?

Tags: java, logging, struts2, log4j, ibatis

I'm working on a Strus2+iBatis project.

When I config the log4j.properties for my project in WEB-INF/classes/...

the iBatis and Struts2 show it's debug information. but sometimes I only want to see my code's log.

I know there is a Hierrachy Logger object in my project. so quesiton is:

1, Is my RootLogger alse the root logger of the iBatis and Struts2 ?

2, How to swith off those 3rd lib's log information?

3, In which way the log4j put my logger in the Hierrachy ? (I guess is: if the logger name is "com.domain.proj.pkg" then log4j will create "com"->"domain"->"proj" 3 namespace and put my logger "pkg" in this namespace)

Comment: What I've found to do similar things, and needed this last week, is configuring struts and iBatis logger by code, not in properties file and disabling, for example, freemarker because of the lot of traces it writes. What you mean with "swith off those 3rd lib's log information"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the log4j configuration file to set the log level for Struts2 and iBatis packages to WARN. Following is the settings for Struts2 packages. Similarly add iBatis packages to the list.

```
log4j.logger.com.opensymphony.xwork2=WARN
log4j.logger.ognl=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.struts2=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.struts2.util.StrutsTypeConverter=WARN
```

If your log4j configuration is a xml file, you will need to add the struts2 and iBatis packages as below.

```
<logger name="com.opensymphony.xwork2" additivity="false">
   <level value="WARN" />
   <appender-ref ref="fileappender" />
</logger>
```